# IOS Create Mask on an image using drawrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I have created a function to draw a line graph, how can I use the line graph as a mask and put it on top of an image?  the image have different color on different height, so what i wanna do is after masking with the line graph, the line graph will display different color on different level. Many thanks for helping me out :)

```
- (void)drawLineGraphWithContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);

    int maxGraphHeight = kGraphHeight - kOffsetY;

    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, kOffsetX, kGraphHeight - maxGraphHeight * data[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < sizeof(data); i++)
    {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, kOffsetX + i * kStepX, kGraphHeight - maxGraphHeight * data[i]);
    }

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) - 1; i++)
    {
        float x = kOffsetX + i * kStepX;
        float y = kGraphHeight - maxGraphHeight * data[i];
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x - kCircleRadius, y - kCircleRadius, 2 * kCircleRadius, 2 * kCircleRadius);
        CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, rect);
    }
    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);


CGPathRef myPath = CGContextCopyPath(ctx);

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer =  [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGPathRef myPath = CGContextCopyPath(ctx);

shapeLayer.path = myPath;


_imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer;



}
```

Comment: You do not `alloc init` Your `CAShapeLayer`.

Comment: As Szlosek said. U will need to initialise the CAShapeLayer

Comment: Have modified the code, but nothing happened....

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it this way.

```
 1. Put the Image into an ImageView.
 2. Since you already have the Path. And rite now, you will get the last
    point as `path.currentPoint`. Add a Line to the `bottomRight` then
    to `bottomLeft` and then to the `startingPoint` of the Path. You
    will need to store the FirstPoint of the Path Somewhere for this.
    Also, all the Path drawing should be in reference to the `bounds` of
    the ImageView.
 3. Create a CAShapeLayer with the path above. `shapeLayer.path = path`.
 4. Set it as mask of the imageView -- imageView.mask = shapeLayer`.
```

Try it out this way. Cheers, have fun.

Comment: thx a lot. I have done the first 3 point. but at point 4
there's an error 
Property mask not found on object of type UIIMageView

Comment: Since you have created a proper path then just set it as mask of the imageView

Comment: Have edited the code, but not working... added few lines in the bottom of the function, am i doing wrong?